# "Blessed is he who, … , shepherds the weak through the valley of Darkness.”

Tags: syntactic-analysis

In *Pulp Fiction*, Tarantino has Jules Winnfield, played by Samuel Jackson, utter the following line from the Bible:

> Blessed is he who, in the name of charity and good will, shepherds the weak through the valley of the darkness.

Now, what is the structure of this sentence? Obviously there is an inversion going on here. But it doesn't seem to fit the ordinary subject-verb inversion. The entire base of the sentence seems flipped.

Perhaps there is no inversion here. "Blessed" is the subject, though being an adjective.

Comment: What has the question to do with *Pulp Fiction*? The quotation is from the Bible.

Comment: 'Blessed' is an [adjective](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blessed?q=Blessed). The subject is 'he' depsite the inversion.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. The question doesn't necessarily involve Pulp Fiction. I only include it here because that's where I first heard it.

Comment: The inversion is straight-forward: "He who, in the name of charity and good will, shepherds the weak through the valley of the darkness is blessed."

Comment: What are Jules?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not an actual Biblical quotation, but it's in the style of [the Beatitudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatitudes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Blessed is he*
> [Complement] + [(Aux) be] + NP[subject]

is an inversion, you are right. The normal word order is

> He is blessed.

When an inversion goes on, the parts of speech do not change, so whatever the word order, the NP headed by ***he*** is the subject and ***blessed*** is its predicative complement. The inversion comes in handy since a relative (*who, in the name of charity and good will, shepherds the weak through the valley of the darkness*) follows which prefers having its referent as close as possible.

This kind of inversion is however literary nowadays, some say even old-fashioned. It is found very often in the Bible (e.g. ***Blessed are the poor, blessed are the pure in heart*** etc.). It is still used in poetry and literature. Tolkien uses it a lot.

In some formal texts you may find such examples as

> ***Equally important*** in terms of forest depletion ***is*** the continuous logging of the forests. (Source: *[English Predicate Inversion](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9f28/f2d3178cf96745233a79af679b49515c3037.pdf)*)

or

> ***Outstanding was the visit*** to the grave by Austrian officials and ten German mayors. (MAG_Time_1928) (Source: *[Modelling adjective phrase inversion](https://varieng.helsinki.fi/series/volumes/16/dorgeloh_kunter/)*)

Comment: Thanks for your examples. The quote left me wondering if we can ever use this kind of inversion without sounding shakespearen. Your examples help.

Comment: Hmmm. The subject is *he who, in the name of charity and good will, shepherds the weak through the valley of the darkness*, not the word *he*!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I really don't understand why people so often get this wrong. I think maybe it's because they aren't ever taught syntactic structures, merely isolated words.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes ok, You are right. I am strongly influenced by my mother tongue where grammar is much more analytical and does not consider the subject a whole phrase but a single word modified by others. I am still not used to the English way of looking at a sentence. I should have said that the subject is this whole NP headed by the pronoun _he_.

Comment: @tchrist I would argue I did not 'get it wrong', but that I am used to a different way of looking at grammar, and analysed the sentence from that perspective. I was taught English in the grammatical categories of my mother tongue, which was probably wrong. I must say though, that I find analytical grammar much less confusing, I guess because I studied it so well.